# Is License Agreement Mandatory for App Store Connect

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect, eula

I'm a new mobile developer and I'm currently developing a flutter app which supports both iOS and Android OS. I'm trying to push my flutter app to App Store Connect, and use the TestFlight's External Testing function as a beta test for my app. I saw that for External Testing, the app might have to be reviewed before it can be tested by testers. And I also saw that there's a section called Test Information, which I assume have to be filled out before submitting a build for review. The problem is, I encounter a section in the Test Information which is called License Agreement. I have no idea what this is, whether it is mandatory or not, and what do I have to write in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave it blank, because it is covered in [TestFlight Terms of Service](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/testflight/sren/terms.html)

> Your use of the TestFlight service (“TestFlight”), including any beta testing of any pre-release Mac, iPhone, iPad, Apple Watch, and Apple TV applications downloaded through TestFlight (“Beta Apps”), is governed by the following terms and conditions (“TestFlight Terms of Service”).